# Determine wall clock time with different Daylight time settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

Windows 7 .Net 4

I have two PCs. One has the SupportsDaylightSavingTime true and one false. Note that the two PCs are next to each other in the office - just one has been forced to run on Standard time year round.

I need to figure out what the local "wall clock time" is regardless of the Daylight setting.

Here is the code I have so far for exploring the issue:

```
Function TimeInfo() As String
    Dim s As String = My.Computer.Name & vbNewLine & "Now: " & Now() & vbNewLine
    s &= "UTC: " & Now.ToUniversalTime & vbNewLine
    s &= "Offset for Now(): " & TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Now.ToShortDateString).Hours & vbNewLine
    s &= "UTC + Offset: " & Now.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Now.ToShortDateString).Hours) & vbNewLine
    s &= "SupportsDaylightSavingTime: " & TimeZoneInfo.Local.SupportsDaylightSavingTime & vbNewLine
    s &= "IsDaylightSavingTime: " & Now.IsDaylightSavingTime & vbNewLine
    Return s
End Function
```

Here is the output from the two PCs (while daylight time is in effect on the Pacific coast) taken from the two PCs about 10 minutes apart:

```
           PC3090-121
        Now: 8/4/2014 1:24:14 PM
        UTC: 8/4/2014 8:24:14 PM
        Offset for Now(): -7
        UTC + Offset: 8/4/2014 1:24:14 PM
        SupportsDaylightSavingTime: True
        IsDaylightSavingTime: True

           PC3090-114
        Now: 8/4/2014 12:39:09 PM
        UTC: 8/4/2014 8:39:09 PM
        Offset for Now(): -8
        UTC + Offset: 8/4/2014 12:39:09 PM
        SupportsDaylightSavingTime: False
        IsDaylightSavingTime: False
```

Unfortunately SupportsDaylightSavingTime overrides IsDaylightSavingTime so I can't tell from the machine time if the wall clock is on daylight time or not. That is all subsequent calls for local info are modified by IsDaylightSavingTime forced to false by SupportsDaylightSavingTime being false.

I've considered using a web IP to get an external take on what time it is but that seems like a bit of overkill. Certainly I should be able to do this on Windows 7 .Net 4.

I must be missing a TimeInfo property/method... I can't see how to find the local time given the calls I'm using.

Comment: isnt it just the one with `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` = False is the one forced to run on Standard year around? That would not work as a general solution, but for 2 PCs in the same office it should.  Does the time or value of that change when the time Falls Back or Springs Ahead?

Comment: My guess is that on the top PC (PC3090-121) Now.IsDaylightSavingTime will change but it will not on the bottom PC as the calendar changes.

Comment: But the TZ information for the one says *I dont do daylight savings* and not likely to change either way.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of works:

```
    Dim dlt As System.Globalization.DaylightTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(Year(Now))
    Dim bDayLightTime As Boolean = (Now > dlt.Start And Now < dlt.End)
    Dim dtPostDate As Date = Now.ToUniversalTime
    If bDayLightTime Then
        dtPostDate = dtPostDate.AddHours(-7)
    Else
        dtPostDate = dtPostDate.AddHours(-8)
    End If
```

The problem is the timezone offset used by AddHours() is hard coded.

I guess I could have used just Now() and added the proper offset - would work for fixed difference, usually 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Noda time? (http://nodatime.org/). It deals with a lot of the timezone issues. Basically makes datetime in .Net a lot more usable in the the way people are used to dealing with in real life (eg: 2 months from now. Not 61 days from now, unless its February etc.)